# Recursively find files that are not publicly readable

Tags: linux, bash, server, public-html

I'd like to recursively find all files in my `public_html` folder that are not publicly readable (i.e. those files that will cause 403 error). Is there a quick bash command for that? I am using Linux servers running apache, if that is relevant. Thanks.

Comment: Try [``cURL``](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts. Could you elaborate your answer please? By the way, I'm looking to do that on the server side (as a administrator to check which files might cause trouble) rather than on the client side (as a user by actually downloading all the files).

Comment: Depends on what kind of server you're using then. You should specify that in your question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `find` command:

```
find . ! -perm -o=r
```

Will search for files within the current directory and subdirectories that has a file permission so that the "others" group cannot read that file.

The manual page for `find` gives some examples of these options.

You can run this command as the `www-data` user:

```
find . ! -readable
```

To find all files that are NOT readable by the web server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, @cleod_ideafix. But `find . -perm -o-r` still returns me files that `others` group has readable access (it seems to return me all files in the folder). But `find . -perm 700` and `find . -perm 600` seem to work.

Comment: @YingXiong: it should be `find . ! -perm -o=r`

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that `find . ! -perm -o=r` is POSIX-compliant, whereas the `-readable` primary (test) is a GNU `find` extension.

Comment: Great pointers, but please fix the fundamentally broken first command.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Note: This answer was originally written while [mcleod_ideafix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30009502/45375) still contained the following *broken* command: `find . -perm -o-r`; the last section of this answer explains why it  cannot work.</sup>

```
find . ! -perm -o=r
```

- matches all files and directories in the current directory's subtree (`.`)

  - to restrict matching to *files* only, append `-type f`.
- which do *not* (`!`) have the *read* permission (`r`) set for security principal "others (world)" (`o`)

This works as intended, as long as all files examined were neither created by the user account in whose context the webserver runs nor belong to a group that the web-server account *is* a member of.
Typically, that is the case.

The **above** command is **POSIX-compliant**.

---

[mcleod_ideafix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30009502/45375) offers a **more robust option** available with *GNU* `find`'s (nonstandard)  `-readable` test:

When run in the context of the webserver's user account (on Linux, `www-data`), this will only match files and directories that the webserver *effectively* cannot read, *irrespective of what user and group own the file*:

```
sudo -u www-data find . ! -readable -prune
```

Note that the `-prune` prevents attempts to descend into unreadable *subdirectories* and thereby suppresses warnings.

- If you want to restrict matching to *files* only, it gets more complicated:
  `sudo -u www-data find . ! -readable \( -type f -print -o -prune \)`

---

As for **what *doesn't* work**:

- Commands such as s **`find . -perm 700`** and `find . -perm 600` **will only match files with that *exact* mode** (`700` translates to `u=rwx,go=`, `600` to `u=rw,go=`), so you'd have to construct commands for all possible variations for the user and group permissions to find all matches of interest.
- **`find . -perm -o-r`** is fundamentally broken and **invariably matches *any* file or directory**:

  - The `-` prefix of the value passed to `-perm` specifies that all the permissions that follow be *set* in matching files.
  - `-perm` only allows *positive* matching of permissions (what IS set as opposed to what's NOT set), so **it is fundamentally impossible to express "match only if this permission is NOT set" logic with just a `-perm` argument *only*.**

    - While `-r` is *syntactically* supported (because it is valid `chmod` syntax), it is *pointless* here and results in a no-op.
    - Technically, `-o-r` tells `-perm` to *subtract* (remove) the read-permission bit for "others" from the starting value of the mode mask used for matching; since that starting value is `000`, or, symbolically, `a=`, any attempt to subtract permissions from that will be a no-op, i.e., have no effect. To put it in the immortal words of  Billy Preston and Bruce Fisher: [Nothin' from nothin' leaves nothin'](https://open.spotify.com/track/5n9QhVJS3XSjSc9kNJNEIU)
    - The *net effect* is that *no restriction whatsoever* is placed on the permissions of potentially matching files or directories, so that *all* items are *unconditionally* matched.
  - Thus, **the only option is to have `-perm` *itself* match *positively* (`-perm -o=r`), and then *negate* the result by placing `find`'s negation operator, `!`**, before it.